# Remove trailing '.0' only postgresql

Tags: postgresql, trailing

I am removing part of a string in my column customer_id in Postgresql.

```
Customer_id : 

N12300 
245007.00 


UPDATE public.meltuniverse SET customer_id=trim(trailing '.0' FROM customer_id::varchar);
```

I only want to remove the .00 at the end and now it returns me :

```
N123
245007
```

How i can fix this?

Comment: not very clear. You want to get rid of .00 from the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Regular Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP):

```
UPDATE public.meltuniverse 
SET customer_id = regexp_replace(customer_id, '\.00$', '')
```

The pattern `'\.00$'` matches exact substring `'.00'` at the end of the string.

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=856e03324e857f41a3a154849906d006)